# UIImagePickerController Subview Not calling delegate. Works as modalViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am writing a camera app using a UIImagePickerController and I would like to add it to the display hierarchy as a subview by doing:

```
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
window = [delegate window];

picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
[window addSubview:picker.view];
[picker viewWillAppear:YES];
[picker viewDidAppear:YES];
```

but when I do it, the delegate is not called.

picker is a UIImagePickerController instance.

If I change the code from adding it as a subview to:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
```

then it all works correctly.  I am fairly sure I have the delegate set correctly.  If there is more code I can post to be more helpful please let me know.  I wasn't sure what to post.

I am doing this for an Adobe Flex Native Extension, so that is why I have to do some extra work to get a reference to the window.  It is also why I cannot use a modalViewController.  The flex app needs to keep its window under the UIImagePickerController in the view hierarchy so I can return to it later.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: after searching further around this site and on the web it looks like there is no way to make this work.  It only works as a modalViewController, why? because apple said so.  If anyone has a workaround for this please let me know, I do not plan to distribute via app store so apples limitations are not an issue to me.

Answer (score 1):

I am as well adding the uiimagepicker as a subview of another view. I fixed this problem by making sure the image picker was a an ivar or by maintaing a strong pointer to it so that it was getting retained.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `UIImagePickerController` only works on modal, or UIPopoverController on iPad.

But you are always free to write your own image picker using ALAssetsLibrary library. or refer to some existing open source implementation like `ELCImagePickerController` https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController